# Can I set up Active Directory Domain Services in Windows Pro or does it require a Windows Server OS?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I want to be able to access ADDS through Microsoft Graph API after setup? I have Windows 10 Pro version. Is it sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be Windows server.

Sources: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/active-directory-domain-services
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-install-prerequisites